# How to only exclude the folders in the root

Tags: windows, command-line, zip, winrar

I want to exclude a folder and its content when i'm doing a `rar` command, the problem is, i only need to exclude the folder in the root, and i do not want to exclude any folder with the same name in other directory or sub directories
Here is my command :

```
"c:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" -afrar a -r -rr30p -m5 -ep1 "C:\React\Backup\Project %mydate%_%mytime%.rar" -x*\.history\ -x*\node_modules\ -x*\build\ "C:\React\Project"
```

My problem is that the `-x*\build\` not only deletes the build folder and its content on the root but also any folder in my other folders that has the same name !!
**How can i change `-x*\build\` so it only and only removes the build folder in the root?**
Thanks.

Comment: how about `-xc:\build` or if you mean the root of c:\react\Project, then `-xc:\react\project\build`

Comment: @LPChip Yeah, this seems to work, thank you.